# Multilevel Inheritace "is-a" relationship?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, extends, multi-level

In Java, if I:

- Create a class A,
- Create a class B which extends class A (this means B "is an" A),
- Then create a class C which extends class B (this means C "is a" B).

Does this also mean that class C is a class A?

Comment: An instance of class `C` is also of type `A`.

Comment: In Java, every class object is also of type `Object`. Does this imply anything?

Comment: All of them extend "object". Being ultimate class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  The "is a" relationship considers the super class, its super class (and so on, up to `Object`), as well as any interfaces implemented by those classes.

Comment: but if we override in class B ,then class C is a class b... now class C will not "is a" with class A...ryt???

Comment: No, a C still is-a A.  Doesn't matter.

Comment: To clarify, in your example, `C` is-a `B`, *and* `C` is-a `A`.  The relationship is transitive: if all `B` are `A`, and all `C` are `B`, then all `C` are also `A`.

Comment: actually what i observed is , constructors wont change. That means even we override anything, constructors will be in restricted ruled,that means we should not leave initializers.

Comment: Constructors will maintain "is a" relationship

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Here is an example: 
If all dogs are mammals and all mammals are animals, all dogs must be animals.

Comment: but if we override in class B ,then class C is a class b... now class C will not "is a" with class A...ryt???

Comment: Rakesh, overriding a method doesn't change the class structure, it changes the behavior of the class. If mammal overrides a method on animal, mammal is still an animal, it just behaves differently.

Answer (score 1):

This question has little to do with Java in fact. It's about knowledge representation models. I can think of ontologies in particular which have much to do with DAGs (directed acyclic graphs). And yes, an "is a" relationship is transitive, so the answer to your question is also "yes". You can Google any of the concepts (from my answer) which you're not familiar with.

Comment: but if we override in class B ,then class C is a class b... now class C will not "is a" with class A...ryt???

Comment: Not right. If "C is B" and if "B is A", then "C is A". This is the transitive thing I was talking about. Btw, just try it out in Java with a simple test (others already suggested this).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `C` is also of type `A`:

```
class A
{
    public A() { }
}
class B extends A
{
    public B() { }
}
class C extends B
{
    public C() { }
}
```

This compiles:

```
A instanceC = new C();
```

Which is only possible because `A` is a super class of `C`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is an example to prove it.

```
    public class A {
    private int a=3;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

public class B extends A {}

public class C extends B{}
```

And to test it

```
C c = new C();
c.getA(); //returns 3
```

Comment: but if we override in class B ,then class C is a class b... now class C will not "is a" with class A...ryt???

Comment: @david If you replace `c.getA();` in your example with `System.out.println(c instance of A);` this would make your example much better and to-the-point, I think.